# Cannot run website in Apache (Cannot use import statement outside a module)

Tags: reactjs, apache, webserver

*I have tried asking on Super User community before, but didn't get any answers so I'm trying my luck here.*

I'm running an Apache web server and decided to host a React application. I have a **nano-react-app** folder which contains the files shown below. I can render the website in debug mode so I know my code is working properly. But when I go online, I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (index.js:1)

which points to the line `import React from 'react';` in **index.js**. To be honest, I don't really understand what the error is  telling me so I don't know where and how to look. All I could figure out is that my **Index.js** file — with a capital `i` — is called from **index.html** with a lowercase `i` and it changes nothing locally but on server-side it returns this error when capitalizing `i`:

> GET http://mywebsite/src/Index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Now.. I have read in another SO question that I should add `type="module"` when calling **index.js** in script tag but now I get this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (index.js:5)

I would highly appreciate any solutions... Thanks!

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers don't support JSX natively. You need to transpile your code to JavaScript by creating a production build. How you do that depends on the toolchain you have selected and is covered [in the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html).

Comment: After having built the application, I get the node_modules folder. Apache wise, what do I need to do so that my website is rendered? Right now, I'm only pointing to  `/var/www/mywebsite` which finds index.html inside.

Comment: The node_modules folder contains the modules that are dependencies. They are used as input for the build, not output. You need to get the output from whatever you did to create the production build.

Comment: I'm not familiar with React and Apache and i'm not quite sure I understand what you are implying when you say input/output... I'm trying to follow guides for `npm run build` but I get no **build/** folder so I'm still clueless.

Comment: You have a bunch of third party modules which are in node_modules, and you have a bunch of code you wrote yourself (including index.js) which are your input. You run through your production build process (and I don't know what process you are using because you've not said) and that should output some files … somewhere … possibly in a `build` directory or a `dist` directory.

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice a **dist/** folder was created after running `npm run build` but I have changed the path to `/var/www/website/dist` in **apache2.conf** and in my website file in `sites-available/mywebsite` and now it fully works. Thank you so much. I've spent too much time on trying to solve this...